# How to turn a table of this SQL format into a CSV?

Tags: sql, csv, export-to-csv

Any recommendations for turning a text document taken from SQL into a CSV? It's for a Wordpress user metadata table.

The data follows this format:

```
(1,1,'nickname','person1'),(2,1,'first_name','person1name'),(3,1,'last_name','person1lastname'),(4,1,'description','yyy')

(1,2,'nickname','person2'),(2,2,'first_name','person2name'),(3,2,'last_name','person2lastname'),(4,2,'description','xxx')
```

etc, except it's all just on a single line.

I want

```
User_ID,nickname,first_name,last_name,description
1,person1,person1name,person1lastname,yyy
2,person2,person2name,person2lastname,xxx
```

I have tried putting it in SQL to CSV converters and they won't accept it. VS Code also doesn't seem to interpret it as a valid SQL table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$str = "(1,1,'nickname','person1'),(2,1,'first_name','person1name'),(3,1,'last_name','person1lastname'),(4,1,'description','yyy')
(1,2,'nickname','person2'),(2,2,'first_name','person2name'),(3,2,'last_name','person2lastname'),(4,2,'description','xxx')";

function sqlConvertToCSV($sqlValuesNotationRows) {
    
    //replace new line to comma
    $santize_str = preg_replace('/\n/',',',trim($sqlValuesNotationRows));

    //Changes ( ) for [ ]. Heads up! Don't take into account the presence of characters inside the values, you may need to use a better regex here...
    $lines = str_replace(['(',')', '\''], ['[',']','"'], $santize_str);
    
    // Convert JSON notation to ARRAY
    $array_items = json_decode("[". $lines ."]");
    
    //Return array list
    //return $array_items;
    
    // implode for create lines of CSV
    $csv = implode("\n", array_map(function($line){
        return implode(",", $line);
    }, $array_items));
    
    // Return csv lines
    return $csv;
}

print_r(sqlConvertToCSV($str));
```

ouput

```
1,1,nickname,person1
2,1,first_name,person1name
3,1,last_name,person1lastname
4,1,description,yyy
1,2,nickname,person2
2,2,first_name,person2name
3,2,last_name,person2lastname
4,2,description,xxx
```